# How to merge or combine high frequency and low frequency data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a column that repeats the low frequency data(such as 1 min stock index price) in high frequency dataframe.
But I don't know how to use pandas to do it.
The following image shows the outcome that I wanted.
Please help me to deal with this problem, Thank you very much!

[image: data sheet]

Comment: I also can't see the image.

Comment: You probably want [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample) or [`align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.align.html#pandas.Series.align)

Comment: I change my link to google plus, so I figure you can see the image this time.

Comment: I have solved this problem. I use the **`pd.to_datetime`** and **`pd.merge`** function.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.
I use the **pd.to_datetime** to convert time to the format H:M:S and then utilize the **pd.merge** to combine the two dataframes.

Comment: It would be really helpful to post the code to your solution as well.